# Python Word Counter Only Counting Words Once

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm trying to make a Python word counter that counts words from a file that was inputted into a dictionary. However, my counter only counts the word once and I'm not sure why. Also, would there be a way not to use the collection Counter ?

```
cloud = {}
val = 0
with open('objects.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for thing in line:
            new_thing = thing.strip(' ')
            cloud[new_thing] = val
            for new_thing in cloud:
                cloud[new_thing] = cloud.get(new_thing, val) + 1
```

Comment: Everytime you encounter the word, you immediately reset the count of all other occurrences to 0: `cloud[new_thing] = 0`

Comment: You might wanna take a look at Counter Dict from the collections module for this, should save you some work. You can just use **Counter(list)** and it will give a dictionary of all words and its count in the list.

Comment: can you give a simple example of the file and the expected results. Maybe there is a better way to tackle the same problem

Comment: the file object names like "toothbrush comb pens pencil" and some are repeated multiple times. my goal is to count how many times the objects appear. so if i see toothbrush twice it'd be-> toothbrush:2

Answer (score 3):

In your code, for each new line, you set

```
cloud[new_thing] = 0
```

which resets the counter for the word `new_thing`.

Since you already use `cloud.get(new_thing, 0)` which will return `0` if the key `new_thing` is not found, you can just remove that line.

Comment: What is the difference between "printing to test if all words are counted correctly" and printing the dictionary? Can you show the code you use for printing?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to initialising the value of each "new_thing" to 0 (`cloud[new_thing] = 0`) as others have noted, there is one other major problem: you try to iterate over `cloud` before adding any element to it (thus, `for new_thing in cloud:` and its block effectively do nothing, because `cloud` is empty). This is not necessary as dictionaries are accessed non-sequentially.

You can either replace

```
new_thing = thing.strip(string.punctuation)
cloud[new_thing] = 0
for new_thing in cloud:
    cloud[new_thing] = cloud.get(new_thing, 0) + 1
```

with just:

```
new_thing = thing.strip(string.punctuation)
cloud[new_thing] = cloud.get(new_thing, 0) + 1
```

or use a `collections.Counter` which, as suggested by others, already does what you're trying to accomplish and would probably make your task easier.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of the `setdefault` function of python dictionary

```
for new_thing in cloud:
                count = cloud.setdefault(new_thing, 0)
                cloud[new_thing] = count + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the part that splits the file in lines and words, and strips the punctuation:

```
def strip_punctuation(lines):
    for line in lines:
        for word in line:
            yield word.strip(string.punctuation)


with open('objects.txt', 'r') as file:
    cloud = collections.Counter(strip_punctuation(file))
```

or, even more concise using `itertools.chain` and `map`:

```
with open('objects.txt', 'r') as file:
    words = itertools.chain.from_iterable(file)
    words_no_punctuation = map(lambda x: x.strip(string.punctuation))
    cloud = collections.Counter(words_no_punctuation)
```

## words

PS: `for thing in line:` does not split the line in words, but in characters. I guess you mean `for thing in line.split():`

then the last option becomes:

```
with open('objects.txt', 'r') as file:
    words_per_line = map(lambda line: line.split(), file)
    words = itertools.chain.from_iterable(words_per_line)
    words_no_punctuation = map(lambda x: x.strip(string.punctuation))
    cloud = collections.Counter(words_no_punctuation)
```